# Owl Carousel - Slide multiple carousels with just one dots carousel slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I have two carousels that I wanted to used, they both have the same amount of items so it will be fine, BUT I want only to have one navigation `dots` and be able to trigger multiple `dots` with the same attributes.

```
$('.div_main .owl-dots').each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('data-index','dot-'+index);
});
$('.owl-dots[data-index="dot-0"] button').each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('data-index','dot-'+index);
});
$('.owl-dots[data-index="dot-1"] button').each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('data-index','dot-'+index);
});
$('.div_main .owl-dot').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var idx = $(this).data('index');



    $('.div_main').each(function() {
        $(this).find('button.owl-dot').eq(0).attr('data-index',idx).click();
    });
});
```

The first function is to get all owl-dots and add `index` attribute to know which is which. the second and third one are the to make them the same, like if this `button` has `data-index="dot-0"` also the other `owl.dots` will be `button[data-index="dot-0"]` so this time, I either want to trigger one of them and ill just find the other `button` with the same `data-index`, but It causes error.

```
  Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I think there is something wrong with my fourth function. Or is there any instances that one `dots` will trigger other `dots` with `owl-carousel`?

Comment: Try `$(this).find('button.owl-dot').eq(idx).click();`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette is there any way to find all the button with the same attribute and trigger them together? It is always this `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error

Comment: Good idea... Try `$("[data-index='"+idx+"']").click()`

Comment: i get the same error

Comment: Hold on... lol... I got it .oO(and about time!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This this click handler:

```
$('.div_main .owl-dot').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if(!$(this).is(".active"){
   var idx = $(this).data('index');
   $("[data-index='"+idx+"']").not(this).click();
  }
});
```

Notice the `.not(this)`!

You had the error, basically because you where saying: «On click on me, click on me.»... Which cause the maximum stack error.

So also checking if the dot already is active will stop the infinite looping.

Comment: I'm having a doubt... It could still trigger a stack error.

Comment: I have something better for you to try... ;)

Comment: Okay please show me something, Im having a hard time with this, `owl-carousel` thing.

Comment: Great to know that it works. ;) There's always a way... It's just a matter of patience.