# Toggling 2 sliders with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, owl-carousel

I have an owl carousel that has a toggle button displayed above it. In the carousel there is a boys set of golf clubs and a girls set of golf clubs. I want users to be able to toggle between the 2 sets but I am a beginner at javascript/jquery. Can someone point me in the right direction to achieve this? Thank you.

```
<section>
<div class="input-wrap">
<input id="input-7" checked="" type="checkbox">
<label for="input-7">Select</label>
</div> 
</section>

<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="row containerCarousel">
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2">
  <div id="home-carousel" class="owl-carousel homeCarousel">
    <div class="slide">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/FB/Bag-Bl@2x.jpg?$staticlink$" alt="gapr chart" class="img-responsive boy"/>
        <img src="images/FB/Bag-Pnk@2x.jpg?$staticlink$" alt="gapr chart" class="img-responsive girl"/>
      </a>
      <h3>01. WHOLE BAG</h3>
    </div>
     </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Owl Carousel - Slide multiple carousels with just one dots carousel slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471114/owl-carousel-slide-multiple-carousels-with-just-one-dots-carousel-slide)

Comment: I'm trying to achieve something different. It's just 1 carousel but I'm trying to incorporate a toggle switch to display a new set of images. For example when the page loads it defaults to show the boys set of clubs but when you hit the toggle switches from the boys set of clubs to a girls set and the boy set hides. I also removed the dots and replaced them with text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's just 1 carousel but I'm trying to incorporate a toggle switch to display a new set of images.

I suggest you to use [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attributes and the jQuery [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method then. And use only one image per `.slide`... Then toggle the `src`.

```js
$("#boyGirlToggle").on("click",function(){
  // Button's text
  
  if($(this).text() == "Boys"){
    $(this).text("Girls");
    dataAttr = "girls";
  }else{
    $(this).text("Boys");
    dataAttr = "boys";
  }
  
  // Change image src.
  $(".slide img").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("src",$(this).data(dataAttr));
  });


}).trigger("click");

$("#home-carousel").owlCarousel({
  loop:true,
  margin:10,
  nav:true,
  responsive:{
    0:{
        items:1
    },
    600:{
        items:3
    },
    1000:{
        items:5
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <div class="input-wrap">
    <input id="input-7" checked="" type="checkbox">
    <label for="input-7">Select</label>
  </div> 
</section>

<br>
<button id="boyGirlToggle">Girls</button><br>
<br>

<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="row containerCarousel">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2">
      <div id="home-carousel" class="owl-carousel homeCarousel">
        <div class="slide">
          <a href="#">
            <img data-boys="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=boys1" alt="gapr chart" class="img-responsive boy" data-girls="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=girls1"/>
          </a>
          <h3>01. IMAGE</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <a href="#">
            <img data-boys="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=boys2" alt="gapr chart" class="img-responsive boy" data-girls="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=girls2"/>
          </a>
          <h3>02. IMAGE</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <a href="#">
            <img data-boys="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=boys3" alt="gapr chart" class="img-responsive boy" data-girls="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=girls3"/>
          </a>
          <h3>03. IMAGE</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <a href="#">
            <img data-boys="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=boys4" alt="gapr chart" class="img-responsive boy" data-girls="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=girls4"/>
          </a>
          <h3>04. IMAGE</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <a href="#">
            <img data-boys="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=boys5" alt="gapr chart" class="img-responsive boy" data-girls="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=girls5"/>
          </a>
          <h3>05. IMAGE</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Have a look in full page mode... ;)